# iOS: Getting this message (not an error) on console- Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, compiler-errors

When I Build my app, it compiles without any problems or errors. But when I run it I see this message in console:

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.
```

Here is my Appdelegate's method which I believe might be causing this(based on other posts Ive seen on SO)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


  PhotosViewController *viewController = [[PhotosViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

  self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
  [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];

  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
```

Is this something that I need to be worried about? My app runs in the simulator even though this message shows up.

Any suggestions on what I should do to get rid of it? What can I do to debug this?

BTW, I have seen other questions on SO with the similar error message, however, none of the scenarios apply to mine so I have posted this question. Its not a duplicate :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
```

Use:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

You can find more details in the [`UIWindow` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006817-CH3-SW33)

Comment: Thanks This worked for me. I donot see the error message anymore